# jQuery - How to make this javascript function global so other function can access it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this example block of code that keeps repeating so many times now.

```
$(function(loadDatabyClickA){
    $('button').live('click', function(){

        selectedAgeType   = $(this).attr('value');

        var x       =   {};

        x.data      =   $('a').attr("data"); //selected item in tree (.liselected)
        x.command   =   $('a').attr("cmd");
        x.option    =   "x";
        x.sessionid =   docCookies.getItem("sessionid");
        x.ageType   =   selectedAgeType;
        x.showData  =   showUnderlyingData;

        var action  =   function(result, status) {

            var x_list  =   "";

            $.each(result, function(i, val){
                x_list  += "<li><h3>"+val.xtitle+"</h3></li>";
            });

        $('#x_view').append(x_list);
        };

        $.post("jsoncommand", JSON.stringify(chart), action)
        .error(function(){
            alert('error');
        });

    })
})
```

How can I extract this block so I can access it from another function? Maybe like using `.extend()`? This block is used by other function like this:

```
$(function(loadDatabyClickB){
    $('button2').live('click', function(){

        selectedAgeType   =   $(this).attr('value');

        var y       =   {};

        y.data      =   $('a').attr("data"); //selected item in tree (.liselected)
        y.command   =   $('a').attr("cmd");
        y.option    =   "y";
        y.sessionid =   docCookies.getItem("sessionid");
        y.ageType   =   selectedAgeType;
        y.showData  =   showUnderlyingData;

        var action  =   function(result, status) {

            var y_list  =   "";

            $.each(result, function(i, val){
                y_list  += "<li><h3>"+val.ytitle+"</h3></li>";
            });

            $('#y_view').append(y_list);
        };

        $.post("jsoncommand", JSON.stringify(y), action)
        .error(function(){
            alert('error');
        });

    })
})
```

You guys can just show me a hint of how to do this because I don't have a clue. I will simplify it myself. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Create a function to generate a click handler based on the "view" that you pass in.

```
function getButtonClickHandler(view) {
    return function () {
        selectedAgeType   =   $(this).attr('value');
        var y       =   {};
        y.data      =   $('a').attr("data"); //selected item in tree (.liselected)
        y.command   =   $('a').attr("cmd");
        y.option    =   view;
        y.sessionid =   docCookies.getItem("sessionid");
        y.ageType   =   selectedAgeType;
        y.showData  =   showUnderlyingData;
        var action  =   function(result, status) {
            var y_list  =   "";
            $.each(result, function(i, val){
                y_list  += "<li><h3>" + val[view + 'title'] + "</h3></li>";
            });
            $('#' + view + '_view').append(y_list);
        };
        $.post("jsoncommand", JSON.stringify(y), action)
        .error(function(){
            alert('error');
        });
    }
}

$(function () {
    $('button').on('click', getButtonClickHandler('y'));
    $('button2').on('click', getButtonClickHandler('x'));
});
```

Comment: Perhaps, using `.on()` would be better? `.live()` has been deprecated in later versions of jQuery ;)

Comment: You need to differenciate between different properties of the `val` as well. So, just change `val.ytitle` to `val[view+'title']` in your code

Comment: What if I want to remove `ageType` and `showData`? If `y_list` is using different DOM such as `<a>`, how do extend the parameter?

Answer (score 0):

create your own class and call your function from your class

```
var youClass = {
        functionName : function() {
            selectedAgeType   = $(this).attr('value');

        var x       =   {};

        x.data      =   $('a').attr("data"); //selected item in tree (.liselected)
        x.command   =   $('a').attr("cmd");
        x.option    =   "x";
        x.sessionid =   docCookies.getItem("sessionid");
        x.ageType   =   selectedAgeType;
        x.showData  =   showUnderlyingData;

        var action  =   function(result, status) {

            var x_list  =   "";

            $.each(result, function(i, val){
                x_list  += "<li><h3>"+val.xtitle+"</h3></li>";
            });

        $('#x_view').append(x_list);
        };

        $.post("jsoncommand", JSON.stringify(chart), action)
        .error(function(){
            alert('error');
        });
        }
    }



//call your function
    $('button').live('click', function(){

        youClass.functionName(parameter);

    })
```

Comment: this wont work since he is using different selectors in the event handler `$('#y_view')` vs `$('#x_view')`

Comment: How do I define what parameter to use?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.bindClick = function(selector, option, view) {
    view = view || '#' + option + '_view';
    $(document).on('click', selector, function(){

        selectedAgeType   = $(this).attr('value');

        var x       =   {};

        x.data      =   $('a').attr("data"); //selected item in tree (.liselected)
        x.command   =   $('a').attr("cmd");
        x.option    =   option;
        x.sessionid =   docCookies.getItem("sessionid");
        x.ageType   =   selectedAgeType;
        x.showData  =   showUnderlyingData;

        var action  =   function(result, status) {

            var list  =   "";

            $.each(result, function(i, val){
                list  += "<li><h3>"+val[option+'title']+"</h3></li>";
            });

            $(view).append(list);
        };

        $.post("jsoncommand", JSON.stringify(chart), action)
        .error(function(){
            alert('error');
        });

    })
})
```

and from any place in your code:

```
bindClick('#button', 'x', '#x_view');
bindClick('#button2', 'y', '#y_view');
```

or just

```
bindClick('#button, #button2', 'x');
```

Comment: this wont work since he is using different selectors in the event handler `$('#y_view')` vs `$('#x_view')`

Comment: with event delegation you could just do `bindClick('#button,#button2');` that way you only bind one handler instead of two

Comment: What if for example, I would like to remove ageType and showData for another event?

Comment: @rolodex than you just need to add another boolean parameter to `bindClick` and surround code that sets `showData` and `ageType` inside the function with `if` that uses that parameter